$\lim_{x \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(x)= \lim_{\rho(x) \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(\rho (x))$
Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$, $\lambda :X \rightarrow X $, be functions between topological spaces.
Let $a,b\in X'$ (here $X'$ is the set of limit points of $X$).
Suppose there is an open neighborhood $V_a$ from $a$ in $E$ such that $\rho :=\lambda |_{V_a}$ is an homeomorphism.
Then $a \in V_a$ (because $V_a$ is open) and $\lambda (a) \in X'$ (since $\rho (\overline{V_a-\{a\}}) \subseteq \overline { \rho(V_a - \{a\})} = \overline {(\rho (V_a) - \{\lambda(a)\})}= \overline{X- \{\lambda(a)\} } $ and $a \in \overline{V_a - {a}}$):
The notation $\lim_{\rho(x) \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(\rho (x))$ has the same meaning as here in my last question.
I'm almost sure that the following is true:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \rho(a)}f(x) =L \iff \lim_{\rho(x) \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(\rho (x))=L$

But I'm finding it difficult to prove the converse $(\impliedby)$. I couldprove the implication $(\implies)$. Could anyone help me?
Proof of the implication $(\implies)$:
Supose $\lim_{x \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(x) = L $ and pickup any neighborhood $U_L$ of $L$ in $Y$. Since $\rho$ is an homeomorlhism, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(x) =\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(\rho(x))$ . Thus, there is an neighborhood $B_{a}$ of $a$ in $V_a$ such that for all $x \in V_a$ :

$ x \in B_{a} \implies f(\rho(x)) \in U_L $

Again, since $\rho$ is an homeomorphism, we have that there is a neighborhood $W_\rho(a)$ of $\rho(a)$ on $X$ such that for all $y \in X$:

$y \in W_\rho(a) \implies \rho ^{-1}(y) \in B_a$

Therefore, for all $x \in X$:

$ \rho(x) \in W_{\rho(a)} \implies x \in B_a \implies f(\rho(x)) \in U_L $


For continuous $f$, you expect $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$ and (if the notation makes sense in the first place?!?) $\lim_{\rho(x)\to\rho(a)} f(\rho(x))=f(\rho(a))$, but in genereal $f(a)\ne f(\rho(a))$

What else can "$\lim_{\rho(x) \rightarrow \rho (a)}f(\rho (x))$" mean than $\lim_{y\to \rho (a)}f(y)$, and how did you prove "the converse (⟸)"? Please edit your post to answer.

@Hagen vom Eitzen due to a lack of attention I ended up putting $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$ instead of $\lim_{x \rightarrow \rho(a)}f(x)$ , which was what I originally wanted to mean. But yes, in the previous case what you said is absolutely right

@VicthorMaths As far as I can tell, this all seems premised on extending shorthand beyond its intended meaning. Something like $x\to a$
may make no sense without context if there are multiple concepts of "convergence". To specify, strong convergence is written $|x-a|\to 0$. That is, $|h|\to 0$ is nothing more than $h\to 0$ [strongly] wrt the norm.

Again, please avoid titles that have nothing but MathJax in them, because they break some navigational shortcuts.
